# curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host, implementing api versioning in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

After implementing api versioning in rails app, not able to set version through curl command as follows:

i am using '**myapp.com:3000/api/movies**' instead of '**localhost:3000/api/movies**'

On running following coommand to set version

```
root@localhost /vagrant/Projects/MyMovieStore (master) $ curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.example.v1' http://myapp.com:3000/api/movies_all
```

Error:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'myapp.com'
```

Comment: _"I am using 'myapp.com:3000/api/movies' instead of 'localhost:3000/api/movies'"_ – what does that mean? Are you just replacing `localhost` with `myapp.com` and expect it to work?

Comment: actually i am running my app from centos using vagrant. and i have set ip name as 'myapp.com'. now the problem is instead of localhost now i should use 'myapp.com:3000' (right now i am using this and app is working fine). @Stefan

Comment: Are you running the `curl` command from within the virtual machine?

Comment: yes from centos

Answer (score 0):

The error is not about versioning, It's about that your machine doesn't recognise `myapp.com` as an alias for `localhost`.

- Edit `/etc/hosts` file and add the following:

`127.0.0.1 myapp.com`

This should do the trick.

Comment: i already tried above. still same problem, i think curl doesn't work host name which contains '.com'.. ?

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmed mentioned you have to add DNS for this new URL by editing the /etc/hosts file and mapping the ip 127.0.0.1 to the myapp.com URL. But, as you can see I don't see you have introduced any versioning to your URL. A versioned URL would look something as follows,

myapp.com:3000/api/v1/movies

Comment: actually problem is not about that, as 3000 is a port on which my app runs. now the question is why curl command is not  accepting my host name that is 'myapp.com'. now, '/api/v1/movies' is one of the route in my rails app.i think, problem is using 'myapp.com' as ip name